# Scrappy doesn't grab span text within div class

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have a problem with retrieving the text from a div class of a website. 
The structure of the page is attached below. I've trying to retrieve that `<span class="product-details__toggler-selected" title="black"`. Only the text 'black' from it.
For the moment I don't retrieve nothing with it.

My xpath is this:

```
color = response.xpath("//div[@class='product-details__toggler-info-title']/p/span[@class='product-details__toggler-selected']/text()").extract()
```

Structure of page:

```
<div class="product-details__toggler-info-title">

    <span class="product-details__toggler-title">Culoare</span>


    <span class="product-details__toggler-selected" title="black"><em class="s-color-bg" style="background-color: #000000">black</em><span class="s-color-name">black</span></span>

</div>
```

Comment: I see no `p` node. Are you sure that provided HTML sample is correct? Did you remove some nodes from it?

Comment: you have a span within a span. //text() will return all descendant text.   therefore, you must used //text() to extract black. if your structure were <span class="product-details__toggler-selected" title="black">
    Black
    </span>  you could use /Text() to find black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required value:

```
//div[@class='product-details__toggler-info-title']//span[@class='product-details__toggler-selected']/span/text()
```

or

```
//div[@class='product-details__toggler-info-title']//span[@class='product-details__toggler-selected']/@title
```